# Oracle: troubles using the parallel option in CREATE TABLE

Tags: oracle, performance, parallel-processing

I am not an expert of oracle, I just write queries and scripts through TOAD but I don't know how oracle works.

In order to make a data analysis I have created several tables in order to build a DB from them.

In order to build them I have used the following command

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NAME                            
TABLESPACE SCHEMASPACE NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS
select [...]
```

with the parallel option active in order to make the server work on more processors.

Once that the DB was created I have tried to do some queries on it but the same query done on the same DB 2 times gave me two different answers. In detail the first time I started the query it returned to me a table with about 2500 rows and the second time it returned to me a table with about 2650 rows.

I have tried to redo the entire process without the parallel option and now it seems to work, but it take too much time and I need to run the process several times, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You're creating tables, not a database (DB). It sounds like you changed the data (or committed changes in another session) between running your queries; or there was a date/time component or some other filter that changed which data was included in the result set; or maybe you just didn't page to the end of the result set the first time. You can make your query parallel with [hints](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51120) or at [session level](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2015.htm#SQLRF53030). Can you provide an reproducible test case?

Comment: The `PARALLEL` option simply marks the table so that if it's queried, Oracle uses a parallel query to get data from that table. It does not make the `create table` run in parallel.

Comment: It would also be useful to state your exact Oracle version. It may be a bug, e.g. see MOS doc ID 1179661.1 for something that *might* sound similar, if you're on 11.2.0.1/2; there may be others affecting other versions. You'd need to talk to your DBA to get that resolved though... Are you sure you really even need extra tables to do your analysis?

Comment: Yes, I need them...we are three people, we have tried to run a query simultaneously and it returned three tables with three different numbers of rows! I think, as you have said in the answer, that the problem is caused by a bug...I will contact our DBA!

Comment: Perhaps if you can actually show us what you are doing, you might get better answers. There is a perception that 99% of problems is a bug; in practice 99% of problems is just user error.

Comment: Three people getting different results simultaneously may well just be due to uncommitted data - I should have stressed that more, but that scenario wasn't clear in the question. [An MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would indeed be useful.